# test legal and illegal argument of a method in JUnit

Tags: java, junit, junit4

If I want to test whether the input is valid, how can I use JUnit4 to test that the method handle the illegal input/argument?

To call `setAge()` method, the argument must be an integer instead of char or string.

```
@Test
public void testWHetherInputValid() {
    Person p = new Person();
    String s = "abc";
    p.setAge(s); // but actually, the correct input must be an integer
}
```

Comment: What is `setAge` supposed to do if given invalid input? Once you know that, you can test for it.

Comment: In this case instead of testing your `setAge` method, it would be better to test your input handling and conversion methods, since it should not compile if the parameter is an int

Comment: You could use @Pattern annotation and then   
use hibernate validator to validate - validator.validate(p);

Comment: Java is strongly typed, so you cannot pass an `int` where a `String` has been declared. So if `Person#setAge` is actually `Person#setAge(int)`, your code won't even compile. The compiler will tell you he cannot find `Person#setAge(String)` method.

Answer (score 5):

If `setAge` receives an `int`, there's no point in writing a test that will pass a `String` to it - such a call won't even compile.

Tests are for catching runtime mistakes the compiler cannot detect. For example, let's assume that a `Person`'s age must be a positive integer. Passing `-1` should, for example, cause the function to throw an `IllegalArgumentException` - which could be tested by specifying the expected exception in the `@Test` annotation:

```
@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void testWHetherInputValid() {
    Person p = new Person();
    int invalidAge = -1;
    p.setAge(invalidAge);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have **n** conditions you want to express in a test, you have **n** tests.

Now, if your method is written correctly (that is, it only accepts an `int` as a parameter), then you don't need to test that; Java will inform you of your error at compile time.

If you're accepting some other kind of object as a parameter (dear God why?!), then it depends on how it's implemented.

- If you accept `String`, and you have a hard expectation that it's an integral number (i.e. "123" and not "123.2"), then leverage `Integer#parseInt` and bomb out when you get an `IllegalArgumentException`.  Test that this exception is thrown.

  ```
  @Test(exception=IllegalArgumentException)
  public void testSetAgeWithInvalidNumeralString {
      // exercise your code
  }
  ```
- If you accept `int`, then you may want to do bounds checking.  You'll ***always*** get an `int` in there, so you may as well find something more worthwhile to validate.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you declared your `setAge` method. In the case you mentioned it seems you declared it something like:

```
public void setAge(String s)
```

but if you are interested in just receiving valid numbers, why do you accept a `String` in the first place?

Anyway, assuming that the declaration of your `setAge` is what you intended for some reason, the way in which I have done this is by checking if an exception is thrown in the line that is violating my logic. So, if the exception is thrown, I continue with the other checks, but if it is not thrown, then something went bad in `setAge` and I make the test fail.

My recommendation is that you declare `setAge` to receive only numbers (`int` maybe) and then the compiler will avoid several invalid uses of your method for you. And in the case you receive some invalid number, let's say `-1` then you throw an exception of one of the sub-classes of `RuntimeException` telling the input was not the expected.